# array of arrays

Tags: expansion

In this example I try to define an array of arrays `\vartypes`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\def\varA{A, B}
\def\varB{C, D, E}
\def\vartypes{\varA, \varB}
\foreach \type in \vartypes{
  \foreach \var in \type{
    \foreach \prefix in {var1, var2}{
      \prefix \var
      }
  }
  \\
}
\end{document}
```

The output from the iteration with `\foreach` is

[image],

whereas I expect

[image]

How can I define `\vartypes` as an array of arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following provides the expected output, barring some spurious spaces:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\def\varA{A, B}
\def\varB{C, D, E}
\def\vartypes{\varA, \varB}
\foreach \type in \vartypes{
  \edef\x{\noexpand\foreach \noexpand\var in {\type}}%
  \x {
    \foreach \prefix in {var1, var2}{
      \prefix{} \var
      }
  }
  \\
}
\end{document}
```

Instead of assuming that `\type` will be expanded, we create `\x` which is an expanded version of *only* `\type` in `\foreach \var in {\type}`, and then use that as a prefix to the group following it.

Answer (score 4):

The level 1 cycle is performed with `\type` taking the values `\varA` and `\varB`.

The level 2 cycle for the first iteration is performed on a single item, namely `\varA`, because `\type` is only expanded once.

More precisely, `\foreach` does `\def\type{\varA}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\eforeach#1in #2{
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{%
    \endgroup\noexpand\foreach\noexpand#1 in
    {\unexpanded\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{#2}}}%
  \x
}


\begin{document}
\def\varA{A, B}
\def\varB{C, D, E}
\def\vartypes{\varA, \varB}
\foreach \type in \vartypes{
  \eforeach \var in \type{
    \foreach \prefix in {var1, var2}{
      \prefix \var
      }
  }
  \\
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More simply:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\def\vartypes{{A,B},{C,D,E}}
\foreach \type in \vartypes{
  \foreach \var in \type{
    \foreach \prefix in {var1, var2}{
      \prefix \var
      }
  }
  \\
}
\end{document}
```